# jQuery selector issue finding image with usemap attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, imagemap

I have an image map in my page:

```
<div id="books">
  <img src="images/books.png" width="330" height="298" border="0" \
   usemap="#map_books" />
  <map name="map_books" id="map_books" alt="books">
    <area shape="poly" coords="17,73,81,288,210,248,254,264, ..." \ 
     href="/about" alt="books" />
  </map>
</div>
```

I have a function that tries to find the image in the document using this map:

```
function(elemId) { // elemId = "#map_books"

  if ($(elemId).attr("tagName") == "MAP") {
    // find image using this map
    var selector = "img [usemap=\\" + elemId + "]"; 
    var img = $(selector);

    if (img.length == 0) {
      console.log("Could not find image using " + selector);
    }
}
```

It fails to find the image.

`Could not find image using img [usemap=\#map_books]`

I've escaped the `elemId` because it [starts with a hash](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and tried variations of selectors.

```
$("img [usemap$=" + elemId.substring(1) + "]")
$("img").find("[usemap=\\" + elemId + "]")
```

Neither find the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, avoid comparing `tagName` case-sensitively as it is not guaranteed a browser will uppercase it. Also `attr('tagname'` is questionable because `tagName` is not an HTML attribute. It happens to work because jQuery redirects most attribute access to property access, but I think `$(elemId)[0].tagName.toLowerCase()==='map'` is a better test.

Comment: `$(elemId)` is a collection and will always have `$(elemId][0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `img` and `[usemap=\#map_books]`.

That results in an attempt to match a child element of `img` with an attribute `usemap` set to `#map_books`.

You should use:

```
var selector = "img[usemap=\\" + elemId + "]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try variations on quoting the usemap value:

```
$("img[usemap='#whatever']");
$('img[usemap="#whatever"]');
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with quoting. Per the docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ his escaping of the hash is correct and, per the docs for that specific selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector quotes are entirely optional

Comment: Since this works too, I'll give you an up vote but I'm awarding this to Dancrumb.

Comment: This works because @John removed your rogue space as well as adding the quotes

Comment: Yup, I realise that now you've explained it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function(elemId) { // elemId = "#map_books"

    if ($('map'+elemId).length) {
        // find image using this map
        var selector = "img[usemap=\\" + elemId + "]"; 
        var img = $(selector);

        if (img.length == 0) {
            console.log("Could not find image using " + selector);
        }
    }
}
```

You had an extra space between img and [] for getting to the img's attributes.

Comment: Thanks, you were just a few mins behind others providing a correct answer.